# What do the icons in Xcode 4's debug area variable list mean?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

Is anyone able to provide a definitive guide to the labelled icons in Xcode 4's debug area variable list? Here's a list of what I have at the moment. I can't figure out what they mean:

[image: Curious Xcode 4 debugger icons]

It's not intuitive. For example, I have BOOL and NSMutableString objects, both with green 'i' icons. I haven't been able to find a list of what these icons mean, either in Xcode's documentation, or online. Thank-you,

Steve.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

They appear to be:

```
L = Local variable
A = Argument
S = Static variable
V = global Variable
R = register
V = instance Variable
E = Expression
```

Here are some links which discuss that part of the interface:

- [debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)
- [debug area overview](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devda5478599)

**edit:** updated with Steve HHH's suggestion
**edit2:** updated following information from a [WWDC 2012 presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), "Debugging in Xcode" (video no longer available)

Comment: What does Register mean exactly? @SteveHHH

Comment: @Honey Register means CPU (or processor) register https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register