# why xcode shows (V) for properties and not (P) for example?

Tags: xcode, swift

Each object has properties and methods in Swift.

Xcode shows (M) for methods, which is a good convention, while it shows (V) for properties,

so why not (P)?

[image]

Comment: Relevant (but older): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917646/what-do-the-icons-in-xcode-4s-debug-area-variable-list-mean

Comment: @Kevin That link is about symbols shown in the debugger. This question is about symbols shown in the documentation. Though they may be similar.